# Does the adjective 'same' ALWAYS have the definite article 'the'?

Tags: articles

I admit. The articles are the most difficult things I find in this language but I'm learning and I'm better than before! I've been reading about the articles in several authentic books and have a question now.

> Does the adjective 'same' ALWAYS have the definite article 'the'?

In fact, looking at complexities of using the articles for zillions of nouns, I feel at least this word -*same* will make me **sure** using the article *the* if this is the case! So, next time on, I'll **never** make a mistake by *not* putting **the** before **same**.

Comment: Short answer, not necessary, because you can say "That same X ...", "Those same Xs ...", etc.

Comment: @DamkerngT. But then *the same X* and *the same Xs* also work!

Comment: I'm not sure if you can always substitute *this* (or *that* or *these* or *those*) with *the*. My feeling is you can't always do that.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Other way round. Am I always allowed to substitute anything before *same* with **the**? It'll still hold the meaning I guess. *That same girl I saw in a pub.* **is equal to** *The same girl I saw in a pub.*

Comment: To answer a slightly different question, *\*a same* is wrong; *same* is definite.  (But you might find that string as part of a larger NP, as in *a same-sex marriage*, where *same* has no article and *a* goes with *marriage*.)

Comment: @MaulikV You *probably* can substitute so. (I said *probably* because I couldn't reach the conclusion myself.) However, I believe that replacing one word with another word always results in a subtle different meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this can answer your question.

> **[same](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/same)**
>   <sup>adjective, adverb, pronoun</sup>
>   **Same** can be used in the following ways:
>   as an **adjective** (after "the," "this," "that," "these," or "those"): We both went to the same school. ♦ Our new competitors are those same people who once asked us to help them.
>   as a **pronoun** (after "the"): I'd do the same if I had the chance.
>   as an **adverb** (after "the"): The twins always dress the same.
>   **The same** is often followed by "as" or "that": Three-twelfths is the same as a quarter. ♦ I've got the same problem as you. ♦ It's the same film that they showed last year.
>   In informal spoken English "the" is sometimes left out before same: We'll meet again next week, same time, same place. But in written English same is almost always used with "the," "this," "that," etc.

The part *"In informal spoken English "the" is sometimes left out before same: We'll meet again next week, same time, same place. But in written English same is almost always used with "the," "this," "that," etc."* confirms my intuition that many people drop the *the* before *same* in real speech.

However, in written English, it's clear that we should use *the same* (or *this*, *that*, etc. *same*).

Comment: +1 it proves almost what I mean. It does take **the** and surprisingly, if you replace 'the' with 'those' (as I said earlier), it'll still make sense.

Comment: Of course, in things like same-sex marriage, things change a bit :P

Comment: This answer is incomplete. There are cases where *same* is used in formal writing without a determiner: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/of-for-to-same .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That example is specific to legal documents, it's not applicable to formal writing in general, and the quoted definition states "almost always" not "always" so the special case is covered. It's not necessary to provide every possible exception to a general rule.